# how to make this in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to make this in codeigniter?

```
$table = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tbluser");
  $row = $table->fetch_assoc();
  do {
   $id = $row['id'];
   $table_child = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tbluser WHERE id = '$id'");
   $row_child = $table_child->fetch_assoc();

   echo $row_child['id'];
  while($row = $table->fetch_assoc());
```

as far as i know in MVC cannot passing data from views to controller.

Comment: It doesn't look like you put any effort into this. The query builder documentation is pretty solid, check it out. Further, what does this have to do with passing data from views to controllers (and yes you are correct, you cannot pass data from views to controllers other than through get and post). Also the nested query doesn't make sense as its from the same table, the first query has all the data you could need.

Comment: CodeIgnorant does not adhere to the MVC architectural pattern. Also read about SQL `JOIN` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the query builder documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html). There are plenty of examples, and the usage is pretty straightforward.

```
$query = $this->db->get('tbluser');

if ($query->num_rows() < 1) {
    echo 'no results found';
    exit;
}

$result = $query->result_array();

foreach ($result as $row) {
    print_r($row);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $some_other_var = $row['someothervar'];
}
```

The nested query in your example doesn't make sense as its from the same table as in the first query of your example; the first query has all the data you could need and this way we touch the database less == better load times.